# How to initialize List inherits from List C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to inherit from list concept and I have a little confusion of initializing  that.

Here is a simple example of my real code, here is my class that inherits from list:

```
public class List_Of_Int : List<int>
{
    public string key{get; set;}
    public List_Of_Int(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

and here is where I need to initialize my variable:

```
    List<int> list_of_int = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    List_Of_Int list_of_list = new List_Of_Int("some_key") **Some Code**
```

I want to assign `list_of_int` to my `list_of_list`, I believe there's a code replace **some code** that will do that, Is it true?

I know I can add by using `AddRange(list_of_int )` later but I'm just wondering if I can do it while declaration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: That code makes no sense. You have a list of entegers and want to initliazie it with a string? Or just add a random property into the new class, with no relations to the list itself? I do agree that it sounds like you should create a class containing a list, rather then inheriting from list.

Comment: Look at the [other constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) of List.  You are missing the one that takes the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering what you are asking actually but I guess this is what probably you are looking at

```
public class List_Of_Int
{
    public List<int> key {get; set;}
    public List_Of_Int(List<int> key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

You can now initialize like

```
List<int> list_of_int = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List_Of_Int list_of_list = new List_Of_Int(list_of_int)
```

Comment: This highlights exactly why you should [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)